# configuration of SRTP in Asterisk 1.8.1

Tags: asterisk, rtp

I am working with jitsi and asterisk 1.8.1. I successfully configured TLS between them. Its working fine.
Now i am configuring SRTP between them.

following are config files.

sip.conf

```
[general]
context=incoming
allowguest=no
alwaysauthreject=yes
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm


tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/newbie.pem
tlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
tlscipher=ALL
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1

[user1]
type=peer
defaultuser=user1
secret=1000
dtmfmode=rfc2833
callerid="User one"
host=dynamic        ; The device must always register
canreinvite=no
nat=yes
encryption=yes
transport=tls

; Deny registration from anywhere first
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
; Replace the IP address and mask below with the actual IP address and mask
; of the computer running the softphone, or the address of the hardware phone,
; either a host address and full mask, or a network address and correct mask,
; registering will be allowed from that host/network.
permit=192.168.51.0/255.255.255.0
context=myphones

[user2]
type=peer
defaultuser=user2
secret=1001
dtmfmode=rfc2833
callerid="User two"
host=dynamic        ; The device must always register
canreinvite=no
nat=yes
encryption=yes
transport=tls

; Deny registration from anywhere first
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
; Replace the IP address and mask below with the actual IP address and mask
; of the computer running the softphone, or the address of the hardware phone,
; either a host address and full mask, or a network address and correct mask,
; registering will be allowed from that host/network.
permit=192.168.51.0/255.255.255.0
context=myphones
```

extension.conf

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
clearglobalvars=no

[incoming]
exten => s,1,Hangup()

[myphones]
exten => user1,1,Set(CHANNEL(secure_bridge_signaling)=1)
exten => user1,n,Set(CHANNEL(secure_bridge_media)=1)
exten => user1,n,Dial(SIP/user1)
exten => user1,n,Hangup()

exten => user2,1,Set(CHANNEL(secure_bridge_signaling)=1)
exten => user2,n,Set(CHANNEL(secure_bridge_media)=1)
exten => user2,n,Dial(SIP/user2)
exten => user2,n,Hangup()

exten => 201,1,Answer()
exten => 201,n,Playback(tt-monty-knights)
exten => 201,n,Hangup()
exten => 202,1,Answer()
exten => 202,n,Playback(welcome)
exten => 202,n,Playback(demo-echotest)
exten => 202,n,Echo()
exten => 202,n,Playback(demo-echodone)
exten => 202,n,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => 202,n,Hangup()
```

i upload srtp module also. it got loaded. But when user1 call to user2 my asterisk server getting segmentation fault and shut down.

Is here any help that how to configure srtp. whether i did it correct or any problem is there..

I already post this problem at http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=84587

THanks in advance.,

Comment: did you mange to resolve the issue? if yes plz share

Answer (score 2):

Asterisk 1.8 has native support for SRTP. So you can easily try this with a Asterisk 1.8.x server. The normal SIP phones are not support for this system. You need to find SRTP supported and TLS supported IP/soft phones for setup this. Use blink soft-phone for this (http://www.icanblink.com). I followed following article to setup secure VoIP system.

For SRTP : http://www.remiphilippe.fr/2011/01/16/asterisk-srtp-with-1-8/

For TLS : https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial, ( You can find ast_tls_cert script from here : https://reviewboard.asterisk.org/r/979/diff/)

Comment: i gone through this link already. Mine TLS is working fine between jitsi and asterisk. But when i enabled SRTP in both side my asterisk server suddenly getting shutdown.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on here but above steps worked for me. Try upgrading your asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question however I'm having the same issue. I cam across this explanation so I thought I'd tag it on the end in case anyone else the same issue (or in our case a lack of understanding!)

Posting can be found here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.voip.sip-communicator.user/921

> Jitsi does support SRTP but it does so through ZRTP key negotiation. This has the advantage of providing end-to-end encryption (contrary to
>   the standard SRTP impl in Asterisk that can be eavesdropped on the
>   server).
>
> It is however not supported by Asterisk and you would hence need to
>   use an actual SIP and RTP proxy in order to have it work.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Emil